# Filling missing time values in an array

Tags: java

In my Java project i make a GET request and i recieve a JSON using Volley.
The data i'm receiving are (unix time as long, float number) and each dataPoint is 10 minutes apart from the other (600 000 ms).
The problem is that when the float value is actually zero the web api i'm using doesn't return any dataPoint so i may have something like this (unix time semplified):

p1 = (0, 100)

p2 = (10, 120)

p3 = (20, 88)

p4 = (30, 86)

*(Here is the gap)*

p5 = (80, 111)

p6 = (90, 128)

p7 = (100, 135)

***how can i transfor that to this:***

p1 = (0, 100)

p2 = (10, 120)

p3 = (20, 88)

p4 = (30, 86)

**p5 = (40, 0)**

**p6 = (50, 0)**

p7 = (60, 111)

p8 = (70, 128)

p9 = (80, 135)

Comment: Why does (80,111) become (80,135) ?

Comment: typing error sorry

Answer (score 0):

If you start with an array that will receive the dataPoints from the api, simply add a new entry in the array with the desired name(p1, p2, p3) and add a new entry everytime you make a request.

- Point[0] -> (0, 100)
- Point[1] -> (10, 120)
- Point[2] -> null
- Point[3] -> null
- Point[4] -> (40, 900)....etc

With this array(list?) you then can use another method to transform its output (p1 = (0, 100), etc...)

Comment: This is already what I do, the problem is that there are no Point[2] and Point[3] in the api